# Vertically middle alignment of two div's overlapping each other inside <li> element

Tags: css, html

Code sample on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9yfEf/)

The div banner and the ul are having a fixed height.
The elements inside the li tag needs to be vertically middle aligned.
I need "info-wrapper" div to be placed exactly on top of "disp-img-contanier" div.
But since I'm using position=absolute and top=0 the "info-wrapper" div moves up.

Any way in which the desired result could be achieved?

HTML:

```
<div class="banner">
<ul class="banner-display clearfix">
    <li class="first-default">
        <div class="disp-img-contanier">
            <!--image goes here-->
            <img src="http://i303.photobucket.com/albums/nn134/gotitlikethat97/Photography/9973TressDunceCap.jpg" width="292px" height="320px" />
        </div>
        <div class="info-wrapper">
            <div class="info-base">
                 <h2>Hover Text</h2>

            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="first-default">
        <div class="disp-img-contanier">
            <!--image goes here-->
            <img src="http://i303.photobucket.com/albums/nn134/gotitlikethat97/Photography/9973TressDunceCap.jpg" width="292px" height="320px" />
        </div>
        <div class="info-wrapper">
            <div class="info-base">
                 <h2>Hover Text</h2>

            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="first-default">
        <div class="disp-img-contanier">
            <!--image goes here-->
            <img src="http://i303.photobucket.com/albums/nn134/gotitlikethat97/Photography/9973TressDunceCap.jpg" width="292px" height="320px" />
        </div>
        <div class="info-wrapper">
            <div class="info-base">
                 <h2>Hover Text</h2>

            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
    .banner {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    height: 550px;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 10px;
}

    .banner .banner-container {
    z-index: 3;
    height: 550px;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 10px;
    width:100%;
}

    .banner-display {
    width: 920px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 0;
    height: 550px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    display: table-row;
}

    .banner-display li {
    width: 292px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-top: 5%!important;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

    .disp-img-contanier {
    height: 320px;
    width: 292px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    overflow: hidden;
}

    .info-wrapper {
    display: block;
    width: 292px;
    height: 320px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background: rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.8);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you need to change a little css around a little bit.

```
.info-wrapper {
  width: 292px;
  height: 320px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

.info-base {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  width: 296px;
  background: rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.8);
  height: 320px;
}
```

and finally, you need to get rid of the padding top in the list elemenst, so:

```
.banner-display li {
  padding-top:0;
}
```

This will vertically center the divs. If you need the padding top, you're going to have more trouble, especially if you are basing it off of a percentage. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick:
http://jsfiddle.net/mikelyons/9yfEf/1/

```
.info-wrapper {
    display: block;
    width: 292px;
    height: 320px;
    position: relative;
    top: -340px;
    background: rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.8);
}
```

Moving the `.info-wrapper` upwards `340px` relative to its position in the document flow places it directly over the element above it.

Comment: I dont want to use top for fixing the layout as I'm looking for something that is responsive

Comment: You could still adjust with media queries, unless you also want it to be fluid...?